# Setting IAR Workbench variables in code

Tags: automation, ide, msp430, iar

I made at .bat file that modifies a .h file containing a #define BUILD_VER so that it gets incremented every time I build.

There is also a #define MAJOR_VER in the same .h file that defines the version that the customers will see.

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the MAJOR_VER and BUILD_VER attached the to the binary output file (I'm using MSP430's so the output is a .txt files.)

So with something like this

```
#define MAJOR_VER 22
#define BUILD_VER 4321
```

...and building "Project_A"

"Project_A.txt" <== current default behaviour

"Project_A_V22_4321.txt" <==What I'm looking for

It would be nice if I could set an IDE variable using these #defines somehow.

This posts answers how to create custom IDE variables, which I didn't see the last time I started looking into this [IAR project variable like $PROJ_DIR$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627397/iar-project-variable-like-proj-dir)

I know I could just write another .bat script to modify the file name, but this seems cleaner to me. And a little more obvious if I were new to the project.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I usually don't do this on normal write/build/test cycle. Instead I have written a deployment script which is called manually from the command line when I want to create the production build. So for me it's separate action, but you perhaps could attach script to post build action? I don't *think* IAR Workbench supports this kind of post build processing out of the box.